# How to expend ListView on whole screen on Android?

Tags: java, android

I have ListView, but it takes up little space and contains scroll. But I need to disable scroll, that ListView take up whole screen. How can I do it?

I need to make list like this: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cineplex.app (2 picture from right). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

For questions like these, you should post your layout XML. In general terms, if you have a ListView in a LinearLayout, you can either set the weight to 1 (if you have other components) or just set the height to fill_parent:

```
<ListView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

or

```
<ListView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on ListView in xml and set width, set height whatever you want.. For ex 20dp , 300 dp etc.
also you can do it like dmon suggested.